# 2nd Harddrive preventing system to boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I've 2 hard drive in my Asus A45V laptop:

1. 240GB SSD (for OS)
2. 500GB HDD (for personal data)

I placed my SSD in HDD slot, and replaced DVD RW with HDD (using caddy).

So here's how my problem showed up:

1. My SSD have two paritions, I have Windows 10 installed in the first partition.
2. I turned off windows fast startup.
3. Then I installed Ubuntu in second parition. Dualboot worked fine using grub as bootloader.
4. I turned on windows fast startup again
5. Now my laptop can't boot, it stuck in Asus logo and I can't enter BIOS using any key. It's completely stuck.

And here's what I've done so far:

1. I removed SSD and reboot. Didn't work.
2. I placed again my SSD, removed my HDD and reboot. **It works**.
3. I removed Ubuntu and grub. Then placed my HDD again, the problem still exists.
4. Removed my HDD, boot windows via bootable USB and doing startup repair, Windows said it can't do a startup repair.
5. Delete hyberfil.sys from my HDD, didn't work.
6. Replaced my HDD with my friend's HDD. **It works fine**.
7. Put my HDD into USB dock (making it external HDD) and plug it in USB port, **works fine**.

So I think it's the problem with my HDD but i don't know what the problem is.

Additional info:

1. Before I have SSD which is just 3 days ago, my Windows 10 is installed in my HDD. I moved it in SSD using mini tool partition > Migrate Os to SSD.
2. Before I have SSD, I enabled paging file for C: and D:.
3. After I moved Windows to SSD, I merged C and D partition on my HDD.
4. There's a silver sticky paper, alumunium foil like that 'protecting' my HDD, the SSD seller moved it on the new SSD.
5. Boot mode is UEFI with legacy support enabled.

**UPDATE**
So i've tried command given by @Hannu and this is the results:

without HDD plugged in

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1864450048 bytes, 3641504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.7 MiB, 36323328 bytes, 70944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240065183744 bytes, 468877312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeaf0f74d

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *       206848 235087871 234881024   112G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       235087872 468877311 233789440 111.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15518924800 bytes, 30310400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00054f40

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30310399 30308352 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

With HDD plugged in:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1864450048 bytes, 3641504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.7 MiB, 36323328 bytes, 70944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 140.9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2433024 bytes, 4752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.5 MiB, 15196160 bytes, 29680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240065183744 bytes, 468877312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeaf0f74d

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *       206848 235087871 234881024   112G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       235087872 468877311 233789440 111.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15518924800 bytes, 30310400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00054f40

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30310399 30308352 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

**EDIT**
I fixed this by reformatting my HDD

Comment: @Hannu sorry but I've said that I've removed Ubuntu

Comment: Boot the Ubuntu install media in "try it"-mode and run it from there. and now I believe `sudo fdisk -l` gives better and relevant info, skip `lsblk`.

Comment: @Hannu okay I'll try it later. Still got deadlines to catch. I'll comment again and post the result.

Comment: ok. Others may chime in as they see the output from fdisk.

Comment: @Hannu I've updated my post, please check it

Comment: You got an addition of loop devices ONLY then: That seems odd to me. I'm not sure why that is. Might these be "snap" packages? `snap list --all` will tell possibly.

Comment: @Hannu I've tried that command with HDD and without HDD plugged in, the results are same.